# how to write `fuser -k -n tcp 80` into a bash script?

Tags: shell-script, apache-httpd

Recently, my site's visitor-ship increased sharply. My Apaches' always crash. I'm seeing lines like these in the httpd/error_log:

```
[Sun Apr 13 08:57:18 2014] [warn] child process 7792 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Apr 13 08:57:20 2014] [error] child process 7925 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
...
```

I will be upgrading my server in the next month. Before that, I'm trying to write a Bash script to automatically restart Apache with a crond job, which checks every 5 minutes.

If `curl`ing some page does not return a 200 code, then `fuser -k -n tcp 80` and `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`.

I'm not good at Bash scripting. I've found some working code which will only restart Apache.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -I http://www.mydomain.com/some-empty-page 2>/dev/null \
    | head -1 | grep -q " 200 OK"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
  echo ""
else 
  /etc/init.d/httpd restart
  echo "wrong $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt
fi
```

How can I modify this to kill all the jobs which use port 80 before restarting?

I'm intending to insert some working line like:

```
else fuser -k -n tcp 80
  /etc/init.d/httpd restart
  echo "wrong $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt
fi
```

NOTE: first `else fuser -k -n tcp 80`, then do `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` in the else case.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: There are more robust monitoring solutions (search [unix.se] or [sf] or the web for “Apache monitoring” or the like). Besides that, I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Just doing `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` will restart Apache, you don't need to kill anything else beforehand.

Comment: @glenn jackman, add `else fuser -k -n tcp 80; /etc/init.d/httpd restart;` the script can not run. I monitor the `/home/myspace/restart_log.txt`.

Comment: "the script can not run": what happens *exactly*?

Comment: i am monitor the `/home/myspace/restart_log.txt`,if no `fuser -k -n tcp 80;`, if the apache crash down, it will insert new line about `wrong $(date)`, but if add `fuser -k -n tcp 80;` no new line insert into `restart_log.txt` and apache remains in a crash status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the usage of port 80. Only one daemon is listening on port 80. It's then forwarding incoming requests to Apache worker daemons. I would simply run the restart script if you're `curl` command doesn't come back with a HTTP status 200.

The stop/start service script should already have provisions in it for dealing with Apache's that are up and not willing to come down.

If you're finding that even after it runs like so:

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd stop
$ pgrep httpd
... returns process ID's...
```

Then you may want to turn your approach around a bit and do this instead:

```
$ /etc/init.d/httpd stop
$ pkill httpd
$ /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

But as I've said. You really should not have to do any of this. The service script `/etc/init.d/httpd` should be robust enough already to properly deal with these situations itself.

#### Modified script

I'd modify what you have in the following way, but otherwise it would be fine to use as is, IMO.

```
#!/bin/bash

response=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --connect-timeout 5  \
    --silent --output /dev/null http://www.mydomain.com/some-empty-page)

if [ $response -eq 200 ]; then
  echo "All's well"
else
  /etc/init.d/httpd restart
  echo "wrong $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt
fi
```

If you want the killing feature, change the else clause:

```
else
  /etc/init.d/httpd stop
  pkill httpd
  /etc/init.d/httpd start
  echo "wrong $(date)" >> /home/myspace/restart_log.txt
fi
```

Depending on how severe a restart you want to perform, you can expand the `pkill` to give harsher kill signals (SIGKILL aka. `-9`) for example, but I would start with the former. If you experience hanging Apache's then add the else clause next. If that still leaves hanging Apache's then use SIGKILL's.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, so can you give me the completed working `#!/bin/bash` script?

Comment: thanks for your update anwser. but still some strange problem. the server still crashed. i tried code in ssh,  `/etc/init.d/httpd stop..............................`, it always in waiting status, type `pkill httpd` before `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`, it will `/etc/init.d/httpd restart..............................` always in waiting status. But type `fuser -k -n tcp 80` then do `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`, the server can restart and worked. what is this problem? I met this problem also in mysql, `fuser -k -n tcp 3306` can work, but `pkill mysqld` sometimes not working before restart. thx

Comment: Have you looked at these processes that are hanging? What do they look like via `ps -eaf | grep httpd`? Also I would take a look at one of them using `lsof -p <pid>` to see what resource they're hanging on AFTER you've given the `/etc/init.d/httpd stop` command. Perhaps you need to `sleep 3` seconds to give them time to stop?

Comment: ok, add sleep 3, seems work well, thanks.